# RefreshIndicator: show without launch onRefresh

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Is there any way to achieve this behavior?

Currently when I use the addPostFrameacallback to force the state to show the indicator, it launch the onRefresh function.

Comment: What is the problem with the onRefresh? Can't you just do nothing? Like this: `onRefresh: null`

Comment: I want to use it as loading indicator in some cases as I use it in normal Android development

Answer (score 2):

To show the RefreshIndicator manually, just attach the `RefreshIndicator()` to a `GlobalKey<RefreshIndicatorState>` by adding the previously created `GlobalKey<RefreshIndicatorState>` to the `key:` property of the `RefreshIndicator()`, and trigger it anytime by running `_refreshKey.currentState.show();`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the indicator as a loading icon, can't you instead use [CircularProgressIndicator](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/CircularProgressIndicator-class.html) and animate it to act the same way?

Comment: I know I can create a loading indicator with the same appearance, but I want the same behavior that in normal Android development to avoid add more boilerplate.

Comment: Alright. I am not a 100 procent sure what you mean by the normal Android development behaviour. As far as I remember from the normal Android it works the same way?

Comment: No, in normal Android you can call show refresh to show the indicator. It doesn't activate the setOnRefreshListener callback, it is only activated when you swipe manually.

Comment: I see, then I have misunderstood you as I have never used it that way,